# Delayed trade reentry

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I’m new to stackoverflow and have some coding experience.  I’m having an issue with my trading algo reentering a trade directly after my stop loss is hit.  I would like to add a variable to delay trade reentry for a certain number of bars even if the conditions are being met.  I’ve tried many different things and I am stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pseudo-code is an example of how to delay your trade entry.

```
//@version=5
indicator("Trade reentry", overlay=true)

var bool    canEnterNewTrade    = true
var bool    enterTradeCondition = true
var bool    stopLossHit         = true
var bool    tradeActive         = false
var int     stopLossBar         = 0
var int     delayInBars         = 20

canEnterNewTrade := not tradeActive and (bar_index - stopLossBar) >= delayInBars

if canEnterNewTrade and enterTradeCondition
    tradeActive := true // enter the trade

if stopLossHit
    stopLossBar := bar_index
    tradeActive := false // exit the trade

plot(na)
```